# YII extensions : how to install time extension?

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

i am a beginner in YII framework, does anyone know how to install this extension?

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/time/

how to install this extension is not explained in its documentation.
i want to convert a timestamp to format "time ago" "1 hour ago" "2 hours ago".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a normal class I think.

Copy file in components o extensions.
In your config/main.php

```
'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',//if Time.php in components
    'ext.*', // if Time.php in extensions

),
```

Use

```
$variable = Time::timeAgoInWords($time)
```

Comment: thx rodriguez, it is work. i just put it in component, and it works